# Fundamental misunderstanding of model in Eloquent (Outside of Laravel)

Tags: php, eloquent

So I've been struggling with using basic eloquent in Slim Framework 2 for quite a while now. This is not my first Eloquent question, but I'm hoping this one actually can be answered unlike my previous one: [Using polymorphic relationships in Eloquent to extend model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618670/using-polymorphic-relationships-in-eloquent-to-extend-model)

I'm working on a simple chemical database for tracking for my University. I've got the Chemicals table with column company_id that correlates to a table called company with just 2 columns, id and company.  chemicals.company_id is a foreign key referencing company.id.

(This, along with several others, like room, and location, started out as Enums, but it quickly became apparent the users would need to be able to add to them.  Editing a DB column to add an enum is obviously not a practical idea.)

In Chemical I have:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Lab_Chemicals\Chemical\company');
}
```

And in Company I have:

```
public function chemical()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Lab_Chemicals\Chemical\chemical');
}
```

They're both in the same namespace (Lab_Chemicals\Chemical) and on their own I can do a

```
$chemicals = $app->chemical->get();
```

and

```
$company = $app->company->get();
```

and get the proper list so the basics appear to be setup correctly, but if I try to do this:

```
$company = chemical::find(1)->company;
```

I get Slim Application Error:

Type: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
Code: 42S22
Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'company.chemical_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `company` where `company`.`chemical_id` = 1 and `company`.`chemical_id` is not null limit 1)

Which brings me to my real question.  Isn't this backwards? Why is it looking for chemical_id in company? I know that this is what it says it does in the docs
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships: "Take note that Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, Phone model is assumed to use a user_id foreign key."

I'd expect it to look for the company where chemical.company_id = company.id.  Where is the flaw in my way of thinking and what can I do to make it work as expected? 
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't a chemical belong to its company? And shouldn't a company have one (or more likely, many) chemicals? I think you've got your relationships backwards, not Eloquent.

Comment: I suppose you are correct. A basic test does in fact get the proper company.  I guess I thought this would not be the correct way, because I have several other tables like company (room, location) and I was assuming Eloquent was smarter than is reasonable to expect.  

Is it then possible to call all of these fields so they are available in one call, or do I have to make a separate call for each relationship?
Thanks

Comment: Well, a company would have a variety of relationships. It `hasMany` employees, chemicals, rooms, etc. Those employees/chemicals/rooms etc. `belongTo` the company. It works in Eloquent the same way it works when you say it out loud in English.

Comment: I was not able to formulate a good answer in the small answer field below, plus I think it's basically a new question anyways. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976712/getting-multiple-relationships-in-eloquent

In case you're interested. Thanks for your help.